# separate js and css files for page--home.tpl.php in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to get a preprocess function to work on my drupal 7 site and am having some difficulty. I was given this.

```
function fource_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['is_home']) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('themes', 'fource');
    drupal_add_js($path . 'js/image_scale.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

-fource is the name of my theme
-I am using the page--home.tpl file as I am using panels for the homepage
? Not sure about the path... ('themes', 'fource')
? Also need to add the css file.

I have no idea what I'm doing here so the most detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Drupal 7 you actually want to do this in `theme_preprocess_html()`. In your theme's `template.php` file you'll need something like this:

```
function fource_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if($vars['is_front']) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/js/image_scale.js');
  }
}
```

The call to `drupal_get_path('theme','fource')` just asks Drupal for the full path to your theme, then you just tack your JS file name on the end.

To be honest, I'm not sure about `is_home` vs. `is_front`, but Google probably knows.

There's also a function `drupal_add_css` (documented [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)).

Comment: the css didn't come through though? drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/css/index_style.css');

Comment: I would start debugging that by checking that the correct header is being added to your HTML (just view source in the browser). If it is, use a tool like firebug to see what happened when it was requested.

Comment: I'm not getting any indication that anything is wrong. Where would i find what i'm looking for with fb? the header seems fine. console only tell me that jquery is undefined after changing $ to jquery and that explains why the script isn't working.